# how to use dll's with php and iis on a 64bit system

Tags: php, iis, com

I'm building a new aplication that needs some com components, but everytime that i try the code

```
$obj = new com("Excel.Application") or die("Unable to create com object");
```

or

```
$obj = new com("zkemkeeper.ZKEM.1") or die("Unable to create com object");
```

or

```
$obj = new com("Bullzip.PDFPrinterSettings") or die("Unable to create com object");
```

I always get a reponse like this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `X.X':
Access is denied. ' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXXX\XXXX.php:X 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXXX\XXXX.php(X): com->com('Excel.Applicati...') 
#1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXXX\XXXX.php on line X
```

Already verified directory, dcom, application, etc settings to allow the use of those components, alreay registered and installed the needed apps, and so on, but at the end i can't get this thing running.

The components are installed and "visible" to applications, already tried with java, vb, c# and those coms works fine, but with php are not working.

Specification of servers are this

- PHP 5.4.9
- IIS 7.5.7600
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit/Windows Server 2008
  R2 64bit (tried on both servers)

any ideas?

UPDATE, finally some com components are working like excel and bullzip, zkemkeeper still not working, can't find any usefull information about that dll, all i have found is a solution editing registry an adding guid and clsid to wow6432 but didn't worked for me, somebody have used that component? (i mean zkemkeeper)

Comment: Are the versions of PHP and Office you have installed the 32- or 64-bit versions?

Comment: both, office is a 2010 32/64 bit, bullzip is 32bit and zmemkeeper is 64bit, more come are needed but nothing seems to work with the normal like excel or word